# How to use alias for sub queries in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, c#-4.0

How should I use the alias in the subquery in order to get the columns from the `subquery`?

```
select R.date, M.bcr from MMS M 
where M.CampaignID in 
(
SELECT MR.CampaignID
FROM [Snipp_Receipts].[dbo].[MMS_Receipts] MR 
where MR.CampaignID = '0ab109b5'
) R
```

**NOTE**: `CampaignID` is the foreign key in both tables.

How I can achieve this? The `inner join` gives more records. The `subquery` has 136 records and I have to get other fields in the `MMS table` corresponding to matching `subquery` records alone.

Comment: Table structure, sample data and expected results would be helpful.  Where are you selecting `r.date`?  Does that come from `mms_receipts`?  Based on your comments, if multiple rows exist in the receipts table, which date should it return?  We need more information to help here...

Comment: Hi. What reference for select statements are you using & what does it say & what does its examples show & why do you think you can write that? What did you learn googling your error message? Please read [ask] & the downvote arrow mouseover text re research. Please read [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You do NOT alias a subquery used inside an `IN(...)` and you CANNOT reference columns of that table in the select clause. You need a JOIN to do that.

```
SELECT
    M.*
FROM MMS M
WHERE M.CampaignID IN (
    SELECT
        MR.CampaignID
    FROM [Snipp_Receipts].[dbo].[MMS_Receipts] MR
    WHERE MR.CampaignID = '0ab109b5'
    ) /* NO alias allowed here */
```

use a inner join

```
SELECT
    M.*
  , MR.date
FROM MMS M
INNER JOIN [Snipp_Receipts].[dbo].[MMS_Receipts] MR ON M.CampaignID = MR.CampaignID
WHERE M.CampaignID = '0ab109b5'
```

Comment: I understand that. Join on FK results in multiple rows where as per the subquery the output should be only 77 records. Not sure how to proceed with it.

Comment: Numbers of expected rows tell us nothing particularly useful to be brutally honest. You would need to supply a sample of your data (both tables)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like single records in MMS are joining to multiple records in MMS_Receipts. Can you aggregate the results from MMS_Receipts? So something like this:

```
SELECT
 M.bcr
,max(MR.date) as [date]
FROM MMS M
INNER JOIN [Snipp_Receipts].[dbo].[MMS_Receipts] MR 
ON M.CampaignID = MR.CampaignID
WHERE M.CampaignID = '0ab109b5'
GROUP BY M.bcr
```